# Como enviar mediante una script de google, la firma de un correo electrónico

Tags: google-apps-script, email

Buen día, tengo una script que a partir del contenido de una hoja de calculo envía un correo electrónico y no tengo problemas para el envío. Necesito que con ese correo que se envía se vaya la firma que tiene configurada la cuenta de correo desde el cual se está enviando, es decir, necesito que al final del correo que se está enviando con la script, se vaya la firma que tiene configurada la cuenta de correo para sus envíos de nuevos mensajes. 
Gracias

Comment: Hola @HéctorHernández , Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te recomiendo un [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por la pagina para poder ganar tu primera medalla, y ver [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para hacer un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y la comunidad acepte de buena forma tu pregunta

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo a la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41729412/1595451) a [Apps Script to get the users signature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41727640/1595451) se debe utilizar la API de Gmail. Lo que no menciona dicha respuesta es que para usar esta se debe habilitar el servicio avanzado como se explica en [How to enable advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services):

> 1. El editor de script, selecciona Recursos > Servicios avanzados de Google...
> 2. En el diálogo que se muestra, haz clic en el botón encender/apagar a un lado del servicios que quieres usar.
> 3. En la parte inferior del diálogo, haz clic en el enlace la consola de API de Google
> 4. En la consola, haz click en el la caja de filtro y escribe una parte del nombre de la API, (por ejemplo "Calendar"), luego cuando
>      veas el nombre haz clic en este.
> 5. En la siguiente pantalla, haz clic en Habilitar API.
> 6. Cierra la Consola de API y regresa al editor de script. Haz clic en el diálogo. El servicio avanzado que habilitaste ahora está disponible
>      en autocompletar.

Luego de haber habilitado el servicio podría usarse la línea de código incluida en la respuesta referida arriba, la cual obtiene la firma predeterminada:

`var signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs.filter(function(account){if(account.isDefault){return true}})[0].signature;`

Comment: gracias por la respuesta. Fue de bastante utilidad

Comment: @HéctorHernández Me da mucho gusto. Si no lo has hecho aún, por favor lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Para completar la respuesta de Rubén, te haría falta un paso más que seria, abrir Apps Scripts y darle click en services y añadir gmail API. con esto te funcionara perfectamente.[image: añadir API de gmail]